# Lodash, find every object given an array of ids

Tags: javascript, lodash

What I have works, but I have a suspicion that there is a lodash method that can do this without the _.map().

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const ids = [1, 2]
const objects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    foo: 'bar'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    foo: 'baz'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    foo: 'quux'
  }
]

const result = _.map(ids, id => _.find(objects, { id }))
console.log(result)
// => [ { id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2, foo: 'baz' } ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `_.intersectionWith()` to get items from the `objects` array, which `id` is equal to an item in the `ids` array:

```js
const ids = [1, 2]
const objects = [{ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2, foo: 'baz' }, { id: 3, foo: 'quux' }]

const result = _.intersectionWith(objects, ids, (o, id) => o.id === id)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Another option is to convert the `objects` array to a object of `{ [id]: obj }` using `_.keyBy()` (the `id`), and then using `_.at()` to get the items from the dictionary using `_.at()`:

```js
const ids = [1, 2]
const objects = [{ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2, foo: 'baz' }, { id: 3, foo: 'quux' }]

const result = _.at(_.keyBy(objects, 'id'), ids)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This solution solved my proplem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for the same, but in plain JS